# Threading in python, how to do?

Tags: python, multithreading, simulation

I'm working on a pseudo-life simulation, it works great so far but I need help on how to do something.

I'm going to paste my code, I explain the problem in a # TODO: comment.

```py
        def speciesMaking(rng): # TODO: After a species is made, do AI(animal_instance) and make sure IT DOESN'T REPEAT!! The reason it doesn't work right now is because I don't know how threading works
            animal_instance.name = namingproc()
            rng2 = random.randint(0, 5)
            if rng == 0:
                animal_instance.isCarnivore=True
                animal_instance.hierarchy=random.randint(3, 10)
                animal_instance.size=random.randint(3, 10)
                print("Carnivore = True")
                
                if rng2 > 4:
                    print("Scavenger = True")
                    animal_instance.isScavenger=True
                    animal_instance.hierarchy=random.randint(3, 10)
                    animal_instance.size=random.randint(3, 10)
                    


            if rng == 1:
               animal_instance.isOmnivore=True    
               animal_instance.hierarchy=random.randint(3, 10)
               animal_instance.size=random.randint(3, 10)
               print("Omnivore = True")
               
               if rng2 > 4:
                   animal_instance.isScavenger=True
                   animal_instance.hierarchy=random.randint(3, 10)
                   animal_instance.size=random.randint(3, 10)
                   print("Scavenger = True")
                   
            
            

            if rng == 2:
                animal_instance.isHerbivore=True  
                animal_instance.hierarchy=random.randint(3, 10)
                animal_instance.size=random.randint(3, 10)
                print("Hervibore = True") 
                

            if rng == 3:
                rng = random.randint(0, 4)
                speciesMaking(rng)
                


            elif rng == 4:
                if rng2 == rng2:
                     animal_instance.isDecomposer=True
                     if random.randint(0, 2) == 1:
                         animal_instance.size=1
                         animal_instance.hierarchy=0
                         animal_instance.isFlora=1

                         print("Flora = True")
                        

                     elif 1 == 1:    
                        
                         
                         animal_instance.hierarchy=0
                         animal_instance.size=0
                         animal_instance.isBacteria=True
                         animal_instance.isDecomposer=True
                         print("Bacteria = True")
                         
                        
                     
                     print("Decomposer = True")
                     

                else:
                    rng = random.randint(0, 4)
                    rng2 = random.randint(0, 5)
                    speciesMaking(rng)

                
            print(animal_instance.name, " = ", animal_instance)
```

Basically, i want to make so that after every animal_instance is created, their AI AI(animal_instance) is done, but the function is an infinite loop, i need to multitask so that MULTIPLE function calls go to different threads so the species can be created as the AI is working

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given us the full code so I cannot actually show you the solution, but I can explain how threads are used in python.

```
animal_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_AI, args=('your args here'))    #create a new thread object that will run the 'target' function with whatever args are defined in 'args'
animal_thread.daemon = True    #this makes the thread close when you exit your program
animal_thread.start()    #actually starts the thread
```

I have put in placeholder names where you would want to insert the actual function and args, but you get the idea. This code would normally go in your **init** function, which would make the thread start whenever an instance is created. Feel free to let me know if you have any other questions!

Answer (score 0):

For your question, I can't say I understand exactly what you are looking for the code to do, so I'll answer you in general terms.

I'm going to suppose the reason you are asking this question is because
if you look up "threading in Python", you will get a *ton* of results talking about the many different ways there are to do threading in Python.

Here is the really quick rundown:

In Python, `threading` does not speed up you program.

Python threads don't actually run in parallel. Instead, Python switches back and further between the running threads to execute code.

This means Python avoids a lot of the pitfalls of concurrent programming, but means it is only best used for IO best tasks, such as downloading a large file in the background while Python does something else.

This is explained, at the time of the Python documentation

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

So the question is why do you want to use "threading".
If performance is what you are after, then you want to use the "multiprocessing" module instead.

Further documentation and explanation of these concepts can be found at the following links:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html - Introduction and documentation for multiprocessing, which can speed up your code using parallelism

[Multiprocessing vs Threading Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python) - Discussion of the difference between multiprocessing and threading

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html - Documentation for threading and how to use that if that fits your application.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html - An alternative way to speed up your program using parallelism using "pools". Concurrent's doesn't work for all use cases, but for the right use case it can make processing a simpler.